# syntax for new ExpectedCondition class in Selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver with python. 
I would like to create an explicit wait for a popup window to appear. Unfortunately, the common methods of the EC module do not include a ready-made solution for this problem. Searching many other posts, I gather that I have to write my own EC condition, with
`.until(new ExpectedCondition() { * the condition and its return arguments *}`.

I am having trouble finding documentation regarding the exact syntax to use to write this properly. There is a java example here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/selenium-users/iP174o0ddw4/l83n5C5rcPoJ. Could somebody either point to the relevant documentation (not on waits generally, but on creating new EC), or simply help me write the python version if the java code I just linked to.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5):

If you want to wait for arbitrary conditions, you don't have to use `ExpectedCondition` at all. You can just pass a function to the `until` method:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def condition(driver):
    ret = False
    # ...
    # Actual code to check condition goes here and should
    # set `ret` to a truthy value if the condition is true
    # ...
    return ret

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(condition)
```

The code above will call `condition` repeatedly until either of the following is true:

- `condition` returns a value that evaluates true,
- 10 seconds have elapsed (in which case an exception is raised).

Comment: Just wanted to point out the source code with sample conditions: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/py/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had occassion to try it, but I think you could use [EC.alert_is_present](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/test/selenium/webdriver/common/webdriverwait_tests.py?name=#307):

```
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as UI

wait = UI.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
alert = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

Inside webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py, `alert_is_present` is defined like this:

```
class alert_is_present(object):
    """ Expect an alert to be present."""
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert.text
            return alert
        except NoAlertPresentException:
            return False
```

You could write it more simply as

```
def alert_is_present(driver):
    try:
        alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
        alert.text
        return alert
    except NoAlertPresentException:
        return False
```

This might give you an idea of how such a condition could be written.

Comment: It worked great when defining my new condition as a class, as you showed above for the alert_is_present method. Thanks!

Comment: I deleted the issue I mentioned because it was a simple error in the way I had defined my class.